# How to default display echarts all tooltip

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, tooltip, echarts

I didn't konw for default to show all tooltip for a echarts map.

this is my tooltip:

```
tooltip: {
          // trigger: 'none',
          trigger: 'item',
          position: function (point, params, dom, rect, size) {
            // 根据params.zone的值设置不同的位置
            let fixedX, fixedY;
            switch (params.name) {
              case "珠三角地区":
                fixedX = 400;
                fixedY = 300;
                break;
              case "粤东地区":
                fixedX = 500;
                fixedY = 250;
                break;
              case "粤西地区":
                fixedX = 300;
                fixedY = 300;
                break;
              case "粤北地区":
                fixedX = 400;
                fixedY = 400;
                break;
              default:
                fixedX = 0;
                fixedY = 0;
                break;
            }

            return [fixedX, fixedY];
          },
          formatter: function (params) {
            if (params && params.data) {
              let zone = params.data.zone;
              //筛选对应的zone区域
              let zoneData = pointdataGD.filter(item => item.zone === zone);
              
              let tipHtml = "";
              tipHtml = '<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">' +
                '<thead>' +
                '<th style=" padding: 8px; background-color: #016831; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; border: 1px solid #b7d5ab;">' +
                params.name +
                "</th>" +
                '<th style=" padding: 8px; background-color: #016831; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold;  border: 1px solid #b7d5ab;">' +
                '预计产量' +
                "(" +
                (params.data.unit || "") +
                ")" +
                "</th>" +
                " </thead>" +
                "<tbody>";

              zoneData.forEach((item) => {
                tipHtml += "<tr>" +
                  "<td style='border: 1px solid #b7d5ab; padding: 8px;'>" +
                  item.city + item.region +
                  "</td>" +
                  "<td style='border: 1px solid #b7d5ab; padding: 8px;'>" +
                  item.value +
                  "</td>" +
                  "</tr>";
              });

              tipHtml += "</tbody>" +
                          "</table>";
              return tipHtml;
            } else {
              return "";
            }
          }
        },
```

it is display effect is which i mouseover a region, it will display all data of this region. But now i need defalut display all region tooltip.

Comment: Maybe [alwaysShowContent](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#tooltip.alwaysShowContent) is what you are looking for?